Using nbstripout as a filter, the git diff of a jupyter notebook is empty. How to temporarily deactivate nbstripout's git filter?
I am using nbstripout to remove the outpout of jupyter notebook before committing them into git.
I had an issue where git status gave the notebook .ipynb file as changed, but git diff didn't show any change. I solved the issue by uninstalling nbstripout from the repository with
cd git_repos
nbstripout --uninstall                                                                        

The problematic notebook file didn't show as "Changes not staged for commit", "modified".
After that I installed nbstripout in the repository again with
nbstripout --install

And the problematic file still didn't show as "Changes not staged for commit:" anymore. The problem appears to be solved by uninstalling and reinstalling nbstripout in the repo.

Is there a way to temporarily turn the nbstripout's git filter off?
Maybe this is not the right question to ask. Is there a way to track down why nbstripout had a problem with that notebook file?

Related links:

How to bypass a git clean filter when adding and committing

